# How to customize the name displayed with Slack bot messages

Tags: slack-api

LiveChat is a Slack bot that provides a chat widget for webpages which you can use to send messages to a Slack workspace. I would like to reproduce the behavior of the LiveChat bot which is somehow able to customize the bot name that appears with messages in Slack with a unique identifier for each user of the webpage with the chat widget.

I see that there is an `as_user` field in the Slack API, but LiveChat does not seem to be using this since clicking the name on any LiveChat message in Slack shows a popup for LiveChat. So the Slack user for all messages seems to be the LiveChat bot, but the name displayed with each message in Slack is customized as a unique id for the given user.

So, I don't want to dynamically control the user for each message. I just want to control the displayed name for each message from the single bot that I'm making.

I don't see anything in the postMessage API to support this. Do you know how to do it?

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Comment: Have you checked the authorship link? Should explain what is needed and in which case based on the value of as_user. Check after the half of the page https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship

Comment: Per the instructions, I tried providing as_user and username. It threw an error that as_user was deprecated. So I removed that. The provided username didn't do anything. I also tried including an icon_url without success. The response from chat.postMessage includes the bot_profile which has the name attribute I want to set. But I don't see a way to set it.